# Django, innodb and row-level locking

Tags: python, django, innodb

I have a table with data to parse and a worker which takes several records from it, process it and saves them back. It also sets flag to 'parsed'.

Now I want to run several instances of the worker and make sure two workers won't pick the same row to process at once. So I need to block it somehow.

I'm using django and from what I read in MySQL manual it's possible to obtain a row-level lock but I can't find any example of doing this properly. The only one says it's extremely slow :) http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2039/

I could have another field saying 'lock until' which would be a timestamp updated to now+X minutes after a row has been selected by the worker. This would shorten the time of the lock (immiediate update after select) and would prevent selecting this row by another worker which would check if it's not 'locked', but the problem of locking between select and update still exists.

thanks!
ian

Comment: Can you post what you have so far? Are you trying to use the ORM or are you using SQL?

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from SQL a much as possible to learn django's ORM. I'm a PHP programmer who evaluates switching to python/django. Of course, it there's no other way I'm ready to use raw SQL.

Answer (score 1):

2 predominant ways to store data in Mysql is MyISAM & InnoDB. Each have their own pros & cons -

1. InnoDB recovers from a crash or other unexpected shutdown by replaying its logs.
2. InnoDB can be run in a mode where it has lower reliability but in some cases higher performance.
3. InnoDB automatically groups together multiple concurrent inserts and flushes them to disk at the same time.
4. InnoDB flushes the transaction log after each transaction, greatly improving reliability.
5. Unlike InnoDB, MyISAM has built-in full-text search
6. MyISAM is still widely used in web applications as it has traditionally been perceived as faster than InnoDB in situations where most DB access is reads.
7. While writing/updating data into a InnoDB table, only that particular row is locked, whereas in MyISAM the entire table is locked.
8. InnoDB provides Full Transaction support.

As far as django models are concerned, they support myisam table creation by default. If you need your tables to have row level locks you need innodb. [This page](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AlterModelOnSyncDB) should be good starting point:

It documents a way to hook into the `post_syncdb` hook to dynamically issue `ALTER` SQL commands to change the engine for the tables.  (Note that this was written 4 years ago, and may need to be updated to the current version of Django).

It should be straightforward for you to add metadata to your models, that specify which storage engine to use for each table.  Then you can modify the above example to key off of that metadata.

Comment: I'm already using InnoDB (added 'OPTIONS': { 'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB;' } in setting.py in database setting), the question is how to obtain a lock, not how to start using innodb :)

Answer (score -1):

with a lock, the second worker would just get stuck waiting for the lock to release.

maybe you could mark entries as "work started on this entry at [timestamp]" before starting to process, and have subsequent workers ignore such rows. you can then have a cron job or similar "releasing" rows that have a timestamp older than some threshold, but not yet marked as "done" (indicating the worker died or something else went wrong)

Comment: This is exactly what I described in 4th paragraph or my question. Still, I need locking to make sure two workers won't collide during selecting rows to process.